How do I prevent ggplotly from altering the label formatting of a ggmosaic facet_grid?
I'm passing a ggplot2 ggmosaic facet_grid to plotly and when I do plotly messes up the formatting of the facet_grid. Plotly overrides the theme() setting in ggplot and adds a legend, replaces the axis labels with 'x' and 'y' and messes up the alignment of the text in facet grid plot labels. Is there some parameter in either facet_grid() or plotly() I can adjust to prevent this?
My code using R's HairEyeColor dataset:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmosaic)
library(plotly)

HECdf <-as.data.frame(HairEyeColor) # returns HEC data table to data frame

my.plot <- ggplot(data = HECdf) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(Eye, Hair), fill = Eye, weight = Freq), show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_mosaic() +                              # specific theme for mosaic plot
  labs(title = 'Hair and Eye Color by Sex',     # adding title, caption
    caption = 'Source: HairEyeColor dataset (R)') +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),         # removing ticks in x and y axes               
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_text(color = 'black', face = 'bold'), 
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = 'black', vjust = 3, face = 'bold'),
    axis.text.x = element_text(color = 'black', angle = 45, hjust = 1),
    axis.text.y = element_text(color = 'black'),
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 2, face = 'bold'), #modifying title
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 1), # modifying caption
    plot.margin = margin(t = 1,  # Top margin
                          r = 1,  # Right margin
                          b = 1,  # Bottom margin
                          l = 1,  # Left margin
                          unit = "cm")) +    # adding margin to plot
  scale_fill_manual(values =  c("#8B4513", "dodgerblue2", "darkgoldenrod", "#1e8449")) +
  facet_grid( ~ factor(Sex, levels = c('Female', 'Male')), # manually adjusting order of   facets
          scales = "free_x")                # adjusting axis label positions per facet plot
my.plot

my.fig <- ggplotly(my.plot)
my.fig

Details of my setup:
Rstudio version: 2024.04.1+748
R version: 4.4.0 (2024-04-24)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.5

packageVersion("plotly"): ‘4.10.4’
packageVersion("ggplot2"): ‘3.5.1’
packageVersion("ggmosaic"): ‘0.3.3’

The ggplot facet_grid looks good:

But when passed to plotly(), it adds a legend, replaces the axis labels with 'x' and 'y', and messes up the alignment of the facet plot labels:

I've looked over the plotly help docs but they seem to specify that formatting is set with theme() for the ggplot. But those settings are being overridden.
